# Lie bracket of vector fields - what have I done wrong?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

Let $X$ be a differentiable manifold and $U \subseteq X$ be an open subset with a chart $\phi: V \to U$ where $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $v,w$ be vector fields on $X$ so that on $U$ we may write them $v = v_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+...+v_n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}$, where $v_1,..,v_n: U \to \mathbb{R}$ are smooth and similarly for $w$. Here we understand $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(b)(x)$ to mean the derivative of $b \circ \phi$ with respect to the i-th coordinate in $\mathbb{R}^n$ evaluated at $\phi^{-1}(u)$ where $b: U \to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth and $u \in U$. Then we define the Lie bracket by

$$[v,w] = \sum_{i=1,j=1}^{n} v_i \frac{\partial w_j}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} - w_j \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$$

We want to check that this definition is independent of the choice of chart $\phi$. In order to better understand this, I tried to calculate a basic example.

Let $U=X=\mathbb{R}$ and $v_1,w_1,b: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $v_1(t)=1,b(t)=t,w_1(t)=t$. Now choose charts
$$x: \mathbb{R} \to U=\mathbb{R}; t \mapsto t  $$ and
$$y: \mathbb{R} \to U=\mathbb{R}; t \mapsto 2t  $$

Then $b(x(t))=t$ so $\frac{\partial b}{\partial x} = 1$, $v_1(x(t))=1$ so $\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x} = 0$ and $w_1(x(t))=t$ so $\frac{\partial w_1}{\partial x} = 1$. Thus, for any $u \in U$, we have

$$[v,w](b)(u) = v_1(u) \frac{\partial w_1}{\partial x}(u)\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}(u) - w_1(u)\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x}(u)\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}(u) = 1\times 1\times 1-u\times 0\times 1 = 1$$

On the other hand, $b(y(t))=2t$ so $\frac{\partial b}{\partial y} = 2$, $v_1(y(t))=1$ so $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 0$ and $w_1(y(t))=2t$ so $\frac{\partial w_1}{\partial y} = 2$. Thus, for any $u \in U$, we have

$$[v,w](b)(u) = v_1(u) \frac{\partial w_1}{\partial y}(u)\frac{\partial b}{\partial y}(u) - w_1(u)\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial y}(u)\frac{\partial b}{\partial y}(u) = 1\times 2\times 2-u\times 0 \times 2 = 4$$.

It seems that here the Lie bracket *does* depend on the choice of chart. What have I done wrong?

---

Edited to make the distinction between $w_1$ and $w$ clear and to make clearer what definition of $\partial/\partial x_i$ I'm using.

Comment: By the way, $[v, w] = vw - wv$, and the formula you wrote down is the coordinate formula for $vw - wv$. So the independence of the chart is trivial.

Comment: Yes, I am in fact entirely comfortable with the well-definedness of the Lie bracket and prefer to define it in a coordinate-free manner, I just wanted to work through the coordinate computation as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Informally, we have
$$
\frac{\partial~~}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial ~~}{\partial (2t)} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial~~}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial~~}{\partial x},
$$
and
\begin{align}
v &= 1 = \frac{\partial~~}{\partial x} = 2 \frac{\partial~~}{\partial y},\\
w &= t = t \frac{\partial~~}{\partial x} = 2t\frac{\partial}{\partial y}.
\end{align}
Therefore, in the first chart, we have
$$
[v,w] = \left(1 \frac{\partial t}{\partial x} - t \frac{\partial 1}{\partial x} \right) \frac{\partial~~}{\partial x} = (1 \times 1 - t \times 0)\frac{\partial~~}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial~~}{\partial x},
$$
since $\displaystyle \frac{\partial t}{\partial x} = 1$ (informally, "$x=t$").
In the second chart, we have
$$
[v,w] = \left(2\frac{\partial(2t)}{\partial y} - 2t\frac{\partial 2}{\partial y}\right) \frac{\partial~~}{\partial y} = (2 \times 1 - 2t\times 0)\frac{\partial ~~}{\partial y} = 2\frac{\partial ~~}{\partial y},
$$
since $\displaystyle \frac{\partial (2t)}{\partial y} = 1$ ( informally, "$y=2t$").
This is where you made a mistake: you seem to have considered that $\frac{\partial(2t)}{\partial y} = 2$.
Recall that we have $\displaystyle \frac{\partial~~}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial~~}{\partial x}$, and thus there is no contradiction.

---

If you want to make the very first argument less informal, notice that if $\varphi\colon U \to \Bbb R^n$ is a chart, then the induced tangent frame is defined as
$$
\left.\frac{\partial~~}{\partial x^j}\right|_p = \left[d\varphi_p\right]^{-1} e_j,
$$
with $e_j$ the $j$th vector of the canonical basis of $\Bbb R^n$.
Therefore, if you canonically identify $T_t\Bbb R$ with $\Bbb R$, then
$$
\frac{\partial~~}{\partial x} = \mathrm{Id}^{-1} (1) = 1,
$$
while
$$
\frac{\partial~~}{\partial y} = \left[ 2\mathrm{Id}\right]^{-1}(1) = \frac{1}{2},
$$
hence the equality $\displaystyle \frac{\partial~~}{\partial x} = 2\frac{\partial~~}{\partial y}$.

Recall that $1 \in T_t\Bbb{R}$ corresponds to the derivation $D_1\colon f \mapsto f'(t)$, so that
$$
\frac{\partial (2t)}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{2}D_1(2t) = \frac{1}{2} (t\mapsto 2t)' = \frac{1}{2}\times 2 = 1. 
$$

Hence, for any $f$, the computations in the first chart gives
$$
\forall t\in \Bbb R,\quad \left([v,w]f\right)(t) = \left( 1 \times 1 - t \times 0\right) f'(t)=f'(t),
$$
and those in the second chart give
$$
\forall t\in \Bbb R,\quad \left([v,w]f\right)(t) = \left( 2 \times 1 - 2t \times 0\right) \frac{1}{2}f'(t) = f'(t).
$$

Comment: Can you identify the step (or steps) in my working where I make an error? Also, I'm not entirely sure how the more formal explanation links to the calculation of the Lie bracket

Comment: It is not true that $\partial b / \partial y = 2$: it is $\partial b / \partial y = \frac{1}{2}$. I'm currently editing the more formal explanation so that it is more understandable

Comment: I think there's some confusion here in that I'm taking my charts $\phi: \mathbb{R}^n \to X$, rather than $\phi: X \to \mathbb{R}^n$. I don't understand why $\partial b / \partial y =2$ doesn't follow simply from the definition of $\partial/ \partial y$, nor why any argument to show that $\partial b / \partial y =\frac{1}{2}$ doesn't immediately apply to $w$ as well as $b$

Comment: @ducksforever "charts" from (subsets of) $\Bbb R^n$ to (subsets of) $M$ are usually called *parametrizations*. Anyway, this does not change much: replace each "2" by "$\frac{1}{2}$", $2t$ by $\frac{t}{2}$, and vice versa, since then, the charts in my sense are given by $\varphi(t)=x^{-1}(t) = t$ and $\psi(t)=y^{-1}(t) = \frac{t}{2}$.

Comment: We have, in a very strict and formal sense, that w=b, so why do we not have that $\partial w/\partial y = \partial b/\partial y$? I feel there must be something very basic which I'm failing to understand here

Comment: In a very strict and formal sense, we do not have $w=b$, since $b$ is a function and $w$ is a vector field. Also, the problem with you convention of charts is that for a fixed $t \in \Bbb R$ (a real parameter), $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ **do not** correspond to the same point in the original manifold $\Bbb R$. The first corresponds to the point $p = t$ in the original manifold while the second corresponds to the point $q=2t$ in the original manifold. This makes little to no sense to compare things at the same parameter $t$, since they do not correspond to the same geometric point on the manifold

Comment: @ducksforever Imagine you were considering the circle instead, with parametrizations $x\colon t \mapsto e^{it}$ and $y\colon t \mapsto e^{i 2t}$. It is clear geometrically that there is no reason to compare what happens at $x(t)$ with what happens at $y(t)$, isn't it? For that purpose, I would highly recommend not to work with parametrizations but only with charts, whose domains are subsets of the manifold.

Comment: Apologies, I accidentally forgot to make a distinction between $w$ and $w_1$. What I meant to say was that $w_1=b$ so we should have $\partial w_1/\partial y = \partial b/\partial y$. I don't understand your point about about $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ corresponding to different points in the manifolds. I agree that they do correspond to different points, but I have been careful (unless I made another mistake) to only evaluate things at points $x \in X$ in order to avoid this issue

Comment: @ducksforever What is your definition of $\partial / \partial y$ at a point $x\in X=\Bbb R$ then?

Comment: I have just updated my question to be more specific about this; essentially for any $a: U \to \mathbb{R}$, $\partial a/\partial y$ is the derivative of $a \circ y$ wrt the i-th coordinate in $\mathbb{R}^n$, evaluated at the point $\phi^{-1}(x)$

Comment: @ducksforever $v_1$ and $w_1$ are the coefficients of $v$ and $w$ **in which coordinates**? They won't have to be the same with respect to both $x$ and $y$! I think your main error is then hidden behind that. We do not have $v = v_1 \partial / \partial x = v_1 \partial/\partial y$: this would imply that $\partial /\partial x = \partial/\partial y$.

Comment: Yes! That was exactly my problem, thank you!